# Function that returns a named list with formula (~) tilde and symbols

Tags: r, function, plotly

I am trying to create a function that can return the dimensions for a [`plotly` parallel coordinates plot](https://plot.ly/r/parallel-coordinates-plot/).  In short, this function expects the dimensions in a structure as follows:

```
df %>%
  plot_ly(type = 'parcoords',
          line = list(color = "blue"),
          dimensions = list(
              list(values = ~ column_01),
              list(values = ~ column_02),
              list(values = ~ column_03)
              # etc...
            )
          )
```

For example, given a `data.frame` (e.g. `iris`), I would like to return a list structure that looks like this:

```
# Desired results
list(
  list(values = ~ Sepal.Length),
  list(values = ~ Sepal.Width),
  list(values = ~ Petal.Length),
  list(values = ~ Petal.Width),
  list(values = ~ Species)
)
```

I am close, but I am having trouble with the `formula` (~) part:

```
library(tidyverse)
get_dimensions <- function(df) {
  map(names(df), ~ list(values = rlang::sym(.)))
}

get_dimensions(iris) %>% str
# List of 5
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ values: symbol Sepal.Length
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ values: symbol Sepal.Width
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ values: symbol Petal.Length
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ values: symbol Petal.Width
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ values: symbol Species
```

*Alternatively, if someone knows of a way to automatically pass **all columns** of a data.frame as dimensions to a plotly parcoords plot, please advise!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check the `str` of OP's desired output, it is a `formula` object

```
str(out1)
#List of 5
# $ :List of 1
#  ..$ values:Class 'formula'  language ~Sepal.Length
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
# ...
```

and formula/s can be directly created from strings after wrapping with `as.formula` or `formula`.  The difference is in the environment

> Formulas created with the ~ operator use the environment in which they were created. Formulas created with as.formula will use the env argument for their environment.

Here, we `paste` or `str_c` (from `stringr`) the tilde (`~`) with the strings, after looping through the strings (`names`) with `map` and create the `formula`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
get_dimensions <- function(df) {
   map(str_c("~", names(df)), ~ list(values = as.formula(.x)))
}
out2 <- get_dimensions(iris)
```

-checking with OP's desired output ('out1')

```
all.equal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `call()` to create the formula.

```r
library(magritrr)
get_dimensions <- . %>%
    names() %>%
    lapply(as.name) %>%
    lapply(function (x) list(values = call("~", x)))

get_dimensions(iris)
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$values
# ~Sepal.Length
#
#
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$values
# ~Sepal.Width
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$values
# ~Petal.Length
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]]$values
# ~Petal.Width
# 
# 
# [[5]]
# [[5]]$values
# ~Species
```